# Closure Compiler - Bad Type Annotation. Unknown type (with externs)

Tags: javascript, external, google-closure-compiler

Starting with the basics. I’m using the JavaScript Closure Compiler and got the error `Bad Type Annotation. Unknown type VRPose` I was trying to have a function return a `{VRPose}`. i.e.

```
/**
 * @returns {VRPose}
 */
VRDisplay.prototype.getPose = function() {};
```

I did the obvious thing and tried to define the VRPose like:

```
function VRPose() {};
```

Unfortunately, this didn’t work; I have the same error. How should I go about defining a type/class in Closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I tried

```
goog.forwardDeclare('VRPose');
```

This actually worked fine. And maybe this was correct behavior for defining externs. But it seemed to be to sort of be skirting the problem.

I looked around for a bit more and found that I was missing the @constructor tag. So here's what I have now:

```
/** @constructor */
function VRPose() {};
```

I'm not really sure what the difference between these two is, so if anyone would like to answer the question and include a better explanation, I'd be happy to accept!

Comment: If you never intend to call `new VRProse()` in your code, you can use `@interface` instead of `@constructor`.